# NoReverseMatch at

Tags: python, django

I have this error and I do not find solution, I get the keywords of ID_pedido_ex and cod_experto but I still throw the error, student help please?

```
Reverse for 'entregado_ex' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'id_pedido_ex': 11, 'cod_experto': 'VA-0012 '}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['solicitar/entregar-extra/(?P<id_pedido_ex>\\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>\\d+)/$']
```

Error during template rendering.

button Template html:

```
<a href="{% url "usuario:entregado_ex" id_pedido_ex=ex.id cod_experto=ex.articulo_ex.cod_experto %}" method='GET' type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right"/>Entregar</a>
```

url global:

```
 urlpatterns = [
# Examples:
url(r'^solicitar/', include(urls, namespace="usuario")),
]
```

url app:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^entregar-extra/(?P<id_pedido_ex>\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>[\w-]+)/$',       Update_stockex, name="entregado_ex"),
]
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def Update_stockex(request, id_pedido_ex, cod_experto):
if request.method == 'GET':
   pedido = Pedido_Extra.objects.get(id=id_pedido_ex)
   articulo = Articulo.objects.get(pk=cod_experto)
   articulo.stock -= pedido.cantidad_ex
   articulo.save()
   pedido.estado_ex = 'entregado'
   pedido.fecha_entrega_ex = datetime.now()
   pedido.save()
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/solicitar/pedidos-extra/')
```

models.py:

```
class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    nombre  = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True)
    stock  = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.nombre, self.stock) 


class Pedido_Extra(models.Model):
    articulo_ex       = models.ForeignKey('Articulo')
    especialidad_ex   = models.ForeignKey('Especialidad')
    cantidad_ex       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.articulo_ex, self.especialidad_ex, self.estado_ex, self.cantidad_ex)
```

What is the problem? regards!

Comment: `url(r'^solicitar/', include(urls, namespace="usuario")),`. you included urls instead of the `'app_name.urls'`.

Comment: Yes, this all included urls serve me in others that I have!

Comment: include(urls) where do you get this url from? That is what I am asking

Comment: url app: from django.conf.urls import url, ulr app: from Pedidoapp import urls    Does that answer? Anyway, I have no problems with the url, sir.

Comment: do you have a get_absolute_url method defined in the models

Comment: I have no definite what in the models.

Comment: add your models to the question let me see how I can help you

Comment: Very well estimated, add used models!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs in the regular expression, change the [\ w -] +) /

To:

```
url(r'^entregar/(?P<id_pedido_ex>\d+)/(?P<cod_experto>[^/]+)/$',   Update_stockex, name="entregado_ex"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a get_absolute_url method to get the reverse for the view

```
 class Articulo(models.Model):
    cod_experto = models.CharField(max_length=999, primary_key=True, blank=True)
    ...



    def get_absolute_url(self): 
        return reverse('entregado_ex', kwargs={'id_pedido_ex': pedido.id, 'cod_experto':self.code_experto})`
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this global method? Even throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Usuario's urls.py > set the app_name = usuario

Your issue should be solved.